# Dynamically adding or removing items within a react-hook-forms form and registering the inputs?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hook-form, onsubmit

I'm trying to implement a rather complicated form that has and date picker and input which the user can add multiple of (or delete). That data then gets added to the overall form on submit. How do I get react-hook-forms to register that little dynamic faux form within the real form?

Here's the faux form inputs:

```
          <AddPackagesStyle>
              <Label htmlFor="addedPackages" label="Add Packages" />

              <DatePicker
                id="dateRange"
                selected={startDate}
                selectsRange
                startDate={startDate}
                endDate={endDate}
                placeholderText="select dates"
                onChange={onDateChange}
              />
              <PackageInput
                id="PackageSelect"
                placeholder="Select Package"
                type="text"
                value={name}
                // @ts-ignore
                onChange={(e) =>
                  // @ts-ignore
                  setName(e.target.value)
                }
              />
              <ButtonContainer>
                <button type="button" onClick={clearAll}>
                  Clear
                </button>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  // @ts-ignore
                  onClick={addPackage}
                >
                  Add
                </button>
              </ButtonContainer>
            </AddPackagesStyle>
```

These entries get added to an array in a useState hook:

```
 const [addedPackages, setAddedPackages] = useState<any[]>([])
```

Then this gets rendered in JSX as the add packages:

```
 <ContentSubscriptionWrapper>
              {addedPackages.length !== 0 &&
                addedPackages.map((addedPackage, idx) => (
                  // @ts-ignore
                  <>
                    <ContentSubscriptionColumn>
                      {addedPackage.name && addedPackage.name}
                    </ContentSubscriptionColumn>
                    <ContentSubscriptionColumn>
                      {addedPackage.startDate &&
                        addedPackage.startDate.toString()}
                    </ContentSubscriptionColumn>
                    <ContentSubscriptionColumn>
                      {addedPackage.endDate && addedPackage.endDate.toString()}
                    </ContentSubscriptionColumn>
                    <button type="button" onClick={() => removePackage(idx)}>
                      X
                    </button>
                  </>
                ))}
            </ContentSubscriptionWrapper>
```

So before the form gets submitted, the 'add packages' has to be set. Where do I add the {...register} object to add to the larger form object for submission?

```
const {
    control,
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<any>()
  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    console.log(data)
  }
```

Comment: Sounds like you should use RHF‘s [Field Array](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray). This way you wouldn’t need extra local state.

Comment: This looks like a great solution although I'm trying to figure out how to make the form static but dynamically render the add elements above the form.

Comment: Could you add a small Codesandbox to demonstrate your use case?

Comment: It seems like `watch` might be the trick here. I gather it's like a temporary cache of input values before final submit of form. I just need to understand how to modify the watch([ ...items]) array before submit. Like if the user decides to remove items before submit of form.

Comment: Here is an image of what the form should look like: https://imgur.com/a/nazCAC1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a CodeSandbox trying to reproduce your use case and used Material UI to get it done quickly, but you should get the idea and can modify it with your own components.

[image: Edit BasicDatePicker Material Demo (forked)]

- you should let RHF handle all the state of your form
- use RHF's `useFieldArray` for managing (add, remove) your packages/subscriptions - there is no need to use `watch` here
- use a separate `useForm` for your `<AddPackage />` component, this has the benefit that you will have form validation for this sub form (in case it should be a requirement that all fields of `<AddPackage />` need to be required) - i added validation in the demo to demonstrate this

**AddPackage.tsx**

```
export const AddSubscription: React.FC<AddSubscriptionProps> = ({ onAdd }) => {
  const {
    control,
    reset,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm<Subscription>({
    defaultValues: { from: null, to: null, package: null }
  });

  const clear = () => reset();

  const add = handleSubmit((subscription: Subscription) => {
    onAdd(subscription);
    clear();
  });

  return (
    <Card variant="outlined">
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <Grid container spacing={1} p={2}>
          <Grid item container spacing={1} xs={12}>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Controller
                name="from"
                control={control}
                rules={{ required: "Required" }}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <DatePicker
                    {...field}
                    label="From"
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                      <TextField
                        {...params}
                        fullWidth
                        error={!!errors.from}
                        helperText={errors.from?.message}
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Controller
                name="to"
                control={control}
                rules={{ required: "Required" }}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <DatePicker
                    {...field}
                    label="To"
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                      <TextField
                        {...params}
                        fullWidth
                        error={!!errors.to}
                        helperText={errors.to?.message}
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Controller
              name="package"
              control={control}
              rules={{ required: "Required" }}
              render={({ field: { onChange, ...field } }) => (
                <Autocomplete
                  {...field}
                  options={packages}
                  onChange={(e, v) => onChange(v)}
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...params}
                      label="Package"
                      fullWidth
                      error={!!errors.package}
                      helperText={errors.package && "Required"}
                    />
                  )}
                />
              )}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Stack spacing={1} direction="row" justifyContent="end">
              <Button variant="outlined" onClick={clear}>
                Clear
              </Button>
              <Button variant="contained" onClick={add} type="submit">
                Add
              </Button>
            </Stack>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

**Form.tsx**

```
export default function Form() {
  const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm<FormValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      seats: "",
      addOns: false
    }
  });
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "subscriptions"
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log("data", data);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Box display="flex" justifyContent="end" gap={1}>
            <Button variant="outlined">Cancel</Button>

            <Button variant="contained" type="submit">
              Save
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Controller
            name="seats"
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <TextField {...field} fullWidth label="Seats" />
            )}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <AddSubscription onAdd={append} />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <List>
            {fields.map((field, index) => (
              <ListItem
                key={field.id}
                secondaryAction={
                  <IconButton
                    edge="end"
                    aria-label="delete"
                    onClick={() => remove(index)}
                  >
                    <DeleteIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                }
              >
                <ListItemText
                  primary={field.package.label}
                  secondary={
                    <span>
                      {formatDate(field.from)} - {formatDate(field.to)}
                    </span>
                  }
                />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Controller
            name="addOns"
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox checked={!!value} onChange={onChange} />}
                label="Add-ons"
              />
            )}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: This definitely works and a solid solution. Yesterday, as I was trying to implement this, I found a solution that mix and matches react-hook-forms and react-hooks to manage state and make use of `register`, 'shouldUnregister` and `control`. I'm not making use of useFieldArray. Should I just go with what's working? Also appreciate the effort of your answer.

Comment: It's hard to tell not knowing the actual implementation. I guess if it's too much work to refactor it by using `useFieldArray` i wouldn't probably do it. But for future similar use cases i would definitely recommend to use as much of RHF's functionality and state handling for all form related tasks. It's really a very powerful and yet simple to use tool.

Comment: So I did decide to refactor because it's better to consistently do things the react-hook-forms way. One thing that differs on your example is the fact that the added date range has to be editable as well. So in the `fields` iteration, I need to add more `<Control <DatePicker /> />` components. I'm very close except I'm getting a TS error on `control={control}`

Comment: I made an alternative version, where the date range can be modified -> [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicdatepicker-material-demo-forked-xmxbl?file=/demo.tsx), hopefully this can help you fixing the TS error.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm still getting type and linting errors using `field` twice within the same loop that requires ` // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-shadow` Probably the version of Typescript? I'm not using Materialize so I'll have to figure out how to get the created Dates to show the values.

Comment: Also having an issue where 'Add' on `add-subscription` cancels out the actual form Submit button.

Comment: I’m just baffled that yours just works and mind doesn’t

Comment: Ok I see one issue: you're using the materialize version of react-datepicker. I posted another issue that I'm having not being able to edit my entries and have it updated in the form field array:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69763415/onchange-in-controller-of-react-hook-forms-not-updating-date-field-in-formfileda

Comment: Here is an alternative version using `react-datepicker` for handling the dates -> [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicdatepicker-material-demo-forked-l84ws?file=/demo.tsx).